# Return Input from Custom Popup

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a custom modal popup entity. When I need a text value from a user, I make the HTML element visible, then I need to get the value they enter in the text field when they press the "Enter" button.

The problem is that what I'm trying to do doesn't seem to have an easy implementation. I don't think it's possible without Promises, and all attempts so far have not worked. Any ideas on possible solutions?

Comment: Some code sample would certainly help. Also, try breaking down your question into multiple paragraphs and being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I managed to get it myself. I had assumed that the promise would somehow end when it reached the end of its code, but this is not true: it will only continue when I resolve it manually. Therefore when I set the onclick of the button with the only possibility of resolving it, it will wait for the button to be pressed. See my code sample below:

```
var modalPopup() = function() {
  //Display the popup
  document.getElementById("GeneralModalBackground").style.display = "flex";

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    document.getElementById("GeneralSubmitButton").onclick = function() {
      //when clicked, resolve the promise with the inputted value
      let returnVal = document.getElementById("GeneralTextField").value;
      resolve(returnVal);
    }
  });
}

modalPopup().then(function(textNeeded) {
  //do stuff I need to do
});
```